# A Sunday in Galway, Ireland. Are many tourist type things closed?

Tags: sightseeing, ireland

Basically I am going to be in Galway by myself for 4 days in a couple weeks and one day will be a Sunday. I am curious what I should expect to be closed? I picture some things will be probably be closed all day.

Comment: The pubs'll be open... :) And the Churches!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately for you, [There has been no recent legislation regarding Sunday trading in Ireland, which is regulated by the Shops (Hours of Trading) Act, 1938.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_shopping#Ireland).  As the link indicates, the act is mostly inoperative, and:

"...as a result **most shops and businesses may open whenever they please, including on Sundays** and public holidays."

Supermarkets and convenience stores are often open longer on Sundays.

The only small issue if you want to get started early, is that off-license shops that sell alcohol are not permitted to do so on Sundays until after 12.30pm.

Comment: Thank you for finding that. Sounds like it shouldn't be too much different than in the US in the bigger cities.

Answer (score 2):

You will find that a lot of locally-owned, non 'big name' main street shops wouldn't open, but those in shopping centres (malls) will all be open, as will anything involved in the hospitality industry. You may find a few things don't open until midday though.

Comment: Yep. I had no trouble really. I believe I even still took a tour bus trip that day too.